# Error ("Bodynode mass zero negative") while running other sim engines in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, ros2, simulation, sdformat, ros2-launch

While launching a world through Gazebo while using 'dart' sim engine, I see the following error :

> [gzserver-1] Warning [BodyNode.cpp:498] [BodyNode] A negative or zero mass [0] is set to BodyNode [link], which can cause invalid physical behavior or segfault. Consider setting positive value instead.

I saved a default world file and edited the physics type tag to 'dart' from 'ode'.

I cannot find anything related to this on the internet, Any help will be much appreciated. The SDF file looks like this:

```
  <sdf version='1.7'>

<model name='ground_plane'>
  <static>1</static>
    <link name='link'>
     <collision name='collision'>
      <geometry>
        <plane>
          <normal>0 0 1</normal>
          <size>100 100</size>
        </plane>
      </geometry>
      <surface>
        <friction>
          <ode>
            <mu>100</mu>
            <mu2>50</mu2>
          </ode>
          <torsional>
            <ode/>
          </torsional>
        </friction>
        <contact>
          <ode/>
        </contact>
        <bounce/>
      </surface>
      <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
    </collision>
    <visual name='visual'>
      <cast_shadows>0</cast_shadows>
      <geometry>
        <plane>
          <normal>0 0 1</normal>
          <size>100 100</size>
        </plane>
      </geometry>
      <material>
        <script>
          <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
          <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
        </script>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <self_collide>0</self_collide>
    <enable_wind>0</enable_wind>
    <kinematic>0</kinematic>
  </link>
</model>
<gravity>0 0 -9.8</gravity>
<magnetic_field>6e-06 2.3e-05 -4.2e-05</magnetic_field>
<atmosphere type='adiabatic'/>
<physics type='dart'>
  <max_step_size>0.001</max_step_size>
  <real_time_factor>1</real_time_factor>
  <real_time_update_rate>1000</real_time_update_rate>
  <collision_detector>simbody</collision_detector>
</physics>
<scene>
  <ambient>0.4 0.4 0.4 1</ambient>
  <background>0.7 0.7 0.7 1</background>
  <shadows>1</shadows>
</scene>
<audio>
  <device>default</device>
</audio>
<wind/>
<spherical_coordinates>
  <surface_model>EARTH_WGS84</surface_model>
  <latitude_deg>0</latitude_deg>
  <longitude_deg>0</longitude_deg>
  <elevation>0</elevation>
  <heading_deg>0</heading_deg>
</spherical_coordinates>
<state world_name='default'>
  <sim_time>47 884000000</sim_time>
  <real_time>53 155451615</real_time>
  <wall_time>1696010762 31842923</wall_time>
  <iterations>47884</iterations>
  <model name='ground_plane'>
    <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
    <scale>1 1 1</scale>
  </model>
  <light name='sun'>
    <pose>0 0 10 0 -0 0</pose>
  </light>
</state>
<gui fullscreen='0'>
  <camera name='user_camera'>
    <pose>5 -5 2 0 0.275643 2.35619</pose>
    <view_controller>orbit</view_controller>
    <projection_type>perspective</projection_type>
  </camera>
</gui>
```